# Irrational combination of rationally independent polynomials

Tags: polynomials, irrational-numbers

Let $p_1,\dotsc,p_k: \mathbb{N}  \to \mathbb{Z}$ be rationally independent polynomials with zero constant term. If $t_1,\dotsc,t_k \in [0,1)$ are not all rational, is it true that the polynomial
$$p(n)=\sum_{j=1}^k t_j\cdot p_j(n)$$
has at least one irrational coefficient?

By assumption, if $q_1,\dotsc,q_k \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $d=\max_{j=1,\dotsc,k}(\deg(p_j))$, then for the polynomial
$$q(n)=\sum_{j=1}^k q_j \cdot p_j(n) $$
which is of degree at most $d$, there exists one $m\in \{1,\dotsc,d\}$ so that the coefficient of $n^m$ is non-zero.

So, I thought of separating the $t_1,\dotsc,t_k$ as follows; W.l.o.g. there exists $l\in \{2,\dotsc,k\}$ so that $t_1,\dotsc,t_{l-1}$ are irrational and $t_l,\dotsc,t_k$ are rational. Now, if $m$ is the one described above for $q_1,q_2,\dotsc,q_{l-1}=0$ and $q_l=t_l, q_{l+1}=t_{l+1}, \dotsc, q_k=t_k$ we get that in $p(n)$ the coefficient of $n^m$ is (assume that $p_j(n)=a_{j,1}n+a_{j,2}n^2+\dotsb+a_{j,m}n^d$)
$$(t_1\cdot a_{1,m}+\dotsb+t_{l-1}\cdot a_{l-1,m})+(t_l\cdot a_{l,m} +\dotsb+ t_k \cdot a_{k,m}),$$ where the quantity in the second parenthesis is rational and non-zero.

But what about the first parenthesis? If it were necessarily an irrational number I would have finished, but this seems incorrect. So maybe there is another approach, or perhaps, the claim is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: if $p$ has rational coefficients, then (with fixed $p$) the real coefficients $t_j$'s are uniquely determined, since the polynomials $p_j$ are linearly independent (this property does not depend on the ground field).

They may be found by Gauss elimination, and are therefore rational.